# XCode 4 crashes with Git

Tags: iphone, git, github, xcode4

I can load, build and run my app with no errors in XCode 4, apart from Git integration that is!

If I select the master branch and create a new branch and either auto switch or manually switch to the new brach XCode 4 hangs and eventually crashes.

Than when I try to re-open my project it is corrupt!  Lucky I backed it up.

Has anyone else ha this issue?  Thinking I may stick to console git mode!

Any help gratefully received ;-)

OK:

removed git
removed xcode4
installed git
installed xcode4
opened project
in organiser the repositories are there again...cool
select master
create new branch
switch to new branch
activity indicator just spins and spins and spins?
click anywhere else in organiser....crash!

BUT....

open terminal window and git operates as usual add, commit, diff etc, all ok???

Comment: yes XCode4 on an iPhone project, even now with the latest git installed I can use git as before from the terminal but not in XCode4 IDE

Comment: I meant this: does Xcode also crash when a non-iPhone project is used?

Comment: i can create brand new projects and it works, it only seems to be on existing repositories that are affected?  And now I find because I uninstalled the old git version and installed a new one I dont get any listed at all.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now my experience with Xcode 4 tells me that anything that doesn't work is most probably the bug. So your best bet is to submit the [bug report directly to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: looks like XCode4 Git integration isnt all that!  back to terminal and wait for Apple to fix it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build directory and reopenning the project.

That fixed this problem for me.

Comment: i updated to the latest git, removed the build folder and now when I open organizer I have no repositories available.  If I select a working copy (i performed git init in the project folder) I get no repository found!       perhaps it is a as suggested by Eimantas a bug???